# how to get int by using Linq group by DATEPART month in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datepart

I have a StayDormApplications table ,
I have a SQL as below ,

```
var systemFilesItem = _db.StayDormApplications.Single(r => r.Id == dormapplication.Id);
string SQL = "SELECT  sum(days) days from StayDormApplications where poster = '" + LoginAccount + "' and DATEPART(MONTH, Sdate) = '"+ month_name + "' group by DATEPART(MONTH, Sdate);"; //
```

how to convert the SQL  with (c#) LINQ?

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ and create a class model that maps to the database.

Comment: If D-Shih's answer solved you problem, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?view=netframework-4.8) to make it, otherwise, your query seems don't need to use `group by` becuase you filter it on the condition.

```
var systemFilesItem = _db.StayDormApplications
                          .Where(x=> x.poster == LoginAccount && SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", x.Sdate).Value == month_name)
                          .Sum(x=> x.days);
```